# match pattern before and after delimiter in grok

Tags: logstash-grok, grok

I have a pattern similar to "ApplicationID#@EVENTREFERENCE" and I need to split it as key - before the delimiter #@ - and value after #@

I tried through grok debugger: 
(?[^#@]*) but this match the value before #@

```
Expected results:
{
  "ApplicationID": [
    [
      "EVENTREFERENCE"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [common option "add_filter"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#plugins-filters-grok-add_field) at the end of your Grok filter after you have matched your data to create a new field that contains the data that you matched.
It should look something like this:

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{DATA:key}#\@%{GREEDYDATA:value}" }
    add_field => { "%{key}" => "%{value}" }
  }
}
```